# Extracting the sensing date/time over a particular lat/lng in a netCDF file in python

Tags: python, datetime, latitude-longitude, netcdf

I am currently working with multiple netCDF files in python. I am using Sentinel-5P NO2 tropospheric columns over Greater London. I want to plot the individual files as a time series, titled with the passover time over London for each individual swath but I am unsure as how to extract this.

Is there a simple way to which I can extract the passover time of the satellite over a particular lat/lng for each file?

EDIT:
Some more information on the files. They are netCDF files meaning they contain Dimensions, Variables, Attributes and Coordinates. They contain information on Vertical Column Densities of NO2 over London at a spatial resolution of 3.5x7km. I have opened the files with xarray in PyCharm and have further attached an image to provide more information on the variables.

[image]

I essentially need to find the value of delta_time when latitude=51.2 or 51.8. Below is what I have developed so far, however I have around 50 files all with over 100,000 pixels so this is very very slow. Does anyone know how I can improve this?

```
    for i in file_list:

        # Open product - GROUP PRODUCT
        with xr.open_dataset(i, group='PRODUCT') as file:
            print(colored('\nPRODUCT Group:\n', 'blue'), file)

        no2 = file['nitrogendioxide_tropospheric_column'][0]

        for row in no2.coords['latitude']:
            for cell in row:
                if cell == 51.2 or cell == 51.8:
                    print(cell)
                    print(cell['scanline'])
                    scanpoint = (cell['scanline'])
                    scantime = no2['delta_time'].sel(scanline=scanpoint)
                    print(scantime)
                    return scantime
            else:
                continue
```

Comment: A solution for this can only be provided if you provide some basic info about your files. Examples: time and spatial resolution are essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the vectorised NumPy functions to do what you want. Now, I'm not so sure about comparing equality of floats but this should be similar to yours. I haven't specifically used xarray but have used netCDF4, so where it says `<array>` I mean get a numpy (or equivalent) array for that variable/coordinate. Also, note that **I haven't selected an individual time value**, which it looks like you have, but am simply using the whole 3D array of `latitude`s.

```py
import numpy as np

latitude = <3D latitudes array>
delta_time = <2D delta_time array>

# 3D boolean array with our required condition
condition = (latitude == 51.2) | (latitude == 51.8)

# Expand tuple of indices, one for each of the 3 dims, but ignore ground_pixel dim
# Each of these idx arrays is 1D
time_idx, scanline_idx, _ = condition.nonzero()

# Get 1D array of delta_times by using time and scanline indices
delta_times = delta_time[time_idx, scanline_idx]
```

This should leave you with the co-ordinates (`condition.nonzero()`) of all relevant cells in all three dimensions, as well as the `delta_times` of these cells.

Note that you don't need the actual `no2` array if you're not using the actual values and only care about `latitude` and `delta_time`, but you can always get the values of the relevant cells with something like `no2[condition]`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have altered my code to resemble yours and I understand the concept of it. However, when I run it, it runs with no errors but the time_idx and scanline_idx arrays are empty and hence so is the delta_time array. Do you know how I might get around this?

Comment: I finally got it to work! The arrays were emtpy because the condition statement was producing an array completely made up of false values but when I changed it to `condition = (latitude >= 51.2) & (latitude <= 51.8)` it works perfectly. Thank you for your help!